# React app not showing data from api when setting state in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some react code where i'm trying to show a list of data in a table. This is the code. The console.log call in the getPagedData displays the correct results in the console but the render is not showing anything.

Seems to be a timing issue with asynchronous call but im stumped. Any ideas why?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getSearchResults} from '../services/searchService';
import AircraftsTable from '../components/aircraftsTable';
import Pagination from '../components/common/pagination';
import qs from 'qs';

class SearchResults extends Component {
    state = { 
        aircrafts: [],
        totalCount:0,
        currentPage: 1,
        pageSize: 10
     }

     componentDidMount(){
        const { aircrafts, totalCount} = this.getPagedData();
     
        this.setState(aircrafts, totalCount);
    }

     handlePageChange = page => {
        this.setState({ currentPage: page });
      };

    getPagedData = async () => {
        const queryString = this.getQueryString();
        const searchResults = await getSearchResults(queryString);

        const aircrafts = searchResults.data.aircrafts;
        const totalCount = searchResults.data.totalCount;

        console.log(aircrafts, totalCount);
        
        return [ aircrafts, totalCount ];    
    }
 
    getQueryString(){
        let criteria = this.props.history.location.state?.data;
        criteria.currentPage = this.state.currentPage;
        criteria.pageSize = this.state.pageSize;    
        const criteriaString = qs.stringify(criteria);

        return criteriaString;
    }

    render() { 
        const { aircrafts, totalCount, pageSize, currentPage} = this.state;

        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
            <AircraftsTable
                aircrafts={aircrafts}
            />
            <Pagination
            itemsCount={totalCount}
            pageSize={pageSize}
            currentPage={currentPage}
            onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
          />
          </React.Fragment>
         );
    }
}
 
export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: return { aircrafts, totalCount };

Comment: In the getPagedData? tried it didnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're returning an array and not an object from `getPagedData` you need to update your `componentDidMount` to:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const [aircrafts, totalCount] = this.getPagedData();
  this.setState({ aircrafts, totalCount });
}
```

Comment: Ive changed it to return an object instead of an array but still no data.

Comment: and did you also update your `setState` call to have curly braces inside as shown in my answer ?

Comment: Yes i did still no luck.

Comment: try changing `componentDidMount` to  `async componentDidMount` and then change `this.getPagedData();` call to `await this.getPagedData();`.

Answer (score 1):

In `getPageData` function you are returning an array. But you are destructuring an object

```
return [ aircrafts, totalCount ];
```

instead of this

```
return { aircrafts, totalCount };
```

Comment: In componentDidMount are you able to see aircrafts and totalColumn

Comment: this.setState({aircrafts, totalCount}); add curly brace, because your state is an object

Comment: No im not seeing results in componentDidMount. I added curly braces as well.